# Shortcut to paste clipboard contents into RStudio automatically surrounded by quotes?

Tags: r, rstudio

Sometimes we copy/paste a string into RStudio, in which case we need to manually surround the text with quotes.

Is there a native way to paste with automatic quoting?

#### Example

If the clipboard contained `here is my text`, such a shortcut would result in `"here is my text"` being pasted in the R console/script pane.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in R:

```
x <- readClipboard()
x
## [1] "Here is my text"
```

This also works:

```
x <- readLines(stdin())
...paste clipboard into R & press ctrl-z (windows) or ctrl-d (unix)...
x
## [1] "Here is my text"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a way to make the text contents of your Clipboard reusable in a script you can do

```r
dput(readClipboard())
```

This has the benefit of automatically making multi-line text into a concatenated character vector. For example if I copy:

```
Alas, poor Yorick! 
I knew him, Horatio; 
a fellow of infinite jest, 
of most excellent fancy;
```

Then I can do

```
dput(readClipboard())

# c("Alas, poor Yorick! ", "I knew him, Horatio; ", "a fellow of infinite jest, ", 
# "of most excellent fancy; ")
```